# Getting the number rows if the datetime colum value is with a certain interval

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I have a `start-date` value of 2015-01-13 12:00 and `end-date` value of `2015-01-16 12:00`, which is a **4-day** interval. I want to get the number of days a student had an activity in each day of this interval. For example given this dataframe (please consider that there are duplicates as well):

```
userid  |  activityday
111        2015-01-13 12:00
111        2015-01-13 12:00
111        2015-01-14 12:00
222        2015-01-13 12:00
222        2015-01-14 12:00
222        2015-01-15 12:00
333        2015-01-13 12:00
333        2015-01-14 12:00
333        2015-01-15 12:00
333        2015-01-15 12:00
333        2015-01-16 12:00
```

I want to obtain:

```
userid |  days_active
111    |  2
222    |  3
333    |  4
```

I am able to do this using a loop but it takes very long. I wonder if there a handy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df.activityday.dt.date.groupby(df.userid).nunique()

userid
111    2
222    3
333    4
Name: activityday, dtype: int64
```

***what's happening***

- you can access many `datetime` related vectorized functions via the `dt` accessor.  `dt.date` simply returns the `date` part of the `datetime` values.  This is the part that we are concerned with in regards to number of activities within the day.
- I then `groupby` `'useid'` and use the `nunique` function (number unique) and viola.

---

You can add one small bit of formatting to get exactly what you asked for.  Namely `reset_index`

```
df.activityday.dt.date.groupby(
    df.userid
).nunique().reset_index(name='days_active')

   userid  days_active
0     111            2
1     222            3
2     333            4
```

Comment: Wow! Could you please provide some explanations? For example what does `dt.date` makes?